# Returning the position in a list (ML)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

> Define a function which, given a list L, an object x, and a positive 
>   integer k, returns the position of the k-th occurrence of x in L if x
>   appears at  least k times in L otherwise 0. For example, if L is
>   [#"a", #"b", #"c", #"b"],  x is #"b", and k is 2, then the function
>   returns 4.

For this problem, I can't use any auxiliary functions and can't use the length function. Any ideas on how I would go about solving it?

Comment: Practice by writing a function that returns the position of the first occurrence, if there is one. Then expand on that idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assume `find` is the function you have to implement. Two things are immediate from the description:

- `find` returns an integer
- `find` takes at least three arguments (`L`, `x`, and `k`)

Furthermore, functions on lists typically distinguish between two cases: either the given list is empty (`[]`) or it contains at least one element (`y::ys`). Thus we can use the following skeleton for `find`

```
fun find   []    x k = ...
  | find (y::ys) x k = ...
```

You should start by thinking about what to do in either case. If `L` is empty there are definitely no occurrences of `x` in it, thus the result is `0`. Otherwise, `L` consists of a head-element `y` and the remaining list `ys`. If `x` is equal to `y`, we just found an occurrence of `x`, otherwise we have to continue to search in `ys`. According to this, the skeleton can be refined into

```
fun find   []    x k = 0
  | find (y::ys) x k =
      if x = y then ...
      else find ys x k
```

At this point the only remaining part is when `L` is not empty and `x = y`. But since we are interested in the `k`-th occurrence of `x`, we have to check whether we found it or not. This could be done by decreasing `k` each time we find an occurrence of `x` and finally, when we find an occurrence and `k` is `1` at the same time, we found the desired `k`-th occurrence of `x`.

```
fun find   []    x k = 0
  | find (y::ys) x k =
       if x = y andalso k > 1 then find ys x (k - 1)
       else if x = y then ...
       else find ys x k
```

The remaining case is that we found the `k`-th occurrence of `x`. So we should return the index `i` of this occurrence. But where should we get `i` from? In some way we have to compute it inside our function. How to do this, is for you to find out.